# Stop RStudio from automatically displaying matrices

Tags: rstudio

I have a really strange problem that is really annoying me. When I'm working in RStudio, if I use View() (usually by clicking the GUI element in Environment) to look at a matrix, any time I modify that matrix, RStudio behaves as though I had run View() again. This is highly disruptive, because I have to click back to the script view to keep doing whatever I was doing.

This has only started to happen since I ~recently updated RStudio. It doesn't happen with data.frame() data, only matrix(). It also doesn't happen if I opened the viewer with tibble::view instead of utils::View

Version info for my RStudio:

RStudio 2022.12.0+353 "Elsbeth Geranium" Release (7d165dcfc1b6d300eb247738db2c7076234f6ef0, 2022-12-03) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2022.12.0+353 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.1.3 Safari/537.36

I realize there's some stuff that I could do to stop this from happening (refrain from using the GUI, only visualize with tibble::view), but I'd like to avoid having to change my workflow just to avoid this weird bug.

Here's a simple execution of the problem:

```
TestDF = matrix()
View(TestDF) #If I then click back to my script
TestDF = matrix() #Then execute this, RStudio behaves like I used View() again
```

Comment: I'm also having this issue. It happens when I pass a dataframe to as.matrix() and is very annoying

Comment: I also have this problem :/!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in a Markdown.
In my settings chunk, i wrote : `options("print.matrix" = FALSE)` and it solved the issue. Hope that works for you!

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Markdown; I assume you mean using .RMD files in Rstudio? Unfortunately I usually use plain .R script files, and this solution doesn't seem to work in that scenario. Sounds like a good solution for Markdown users, though!